# UITableView overlaps on scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, scroll, overlapping

In my Storyboard I've got a table view.
I'm filling that table view using data loaded from a JSON file (loaded in viewDidLoad).

In my UITableView I did set "Prototype Cells" to 1 so I can easily select a Accessory. 
My Prototype Cell has a Seque to a new View which needs to show the details of the selected item.

I'm filling my Cells programmatically using this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *videoTableIdentifier = @"VideoCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:videoTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:videoTableIdentifier];

    UILabel * title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,5, 240,20)];
    [cell addSubview:title];
    [title setText:[[videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]];

    UILabel * detail = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,28, 100,10)];
    [cell addSubview:detail];
    [detail setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Year: %@", [[videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"year"]]];

    [cell addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]]]];

    return cell;
}
```

When I start scrolling the following happens:
[image]

So I started searching for a solution and found that I had to set: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:videoTableIdentifier` to "nil".

While I did that, this solved my problem, **BUT** now me Prototype Cell Accessory and Seque are gone so I can't navigate to the next view anymore.

I couldn't find a solution for this on the internets so I decided to ask this.
Would be awesome if someone could help.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that every time you re-use a cell, you are adding new subviews to it, so if you have a cell with some labels, and you reuse it and add more labels, all of them appear overlaped.

I suggest you to make your own custom UITableViewCell with labels on it, and just change the value of the labels every time.

Comment: That's what I thought, because I had read something about recycling the cells, but I couldn't found out how to fix it. And only the text's are overlapping, the images are staying the same even that's also a subview?!

Comment: The images are stacking one of top of the other. Please accept the answer if it helped

Comment: You could actually move the addSubview code inside the  if (cell == nil) condition and it will work fine without subclassing UITableViewCell. But I think it's still a better approach to create a custom subclass

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!title){
    title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,5, 240,20)];
    [cell addSubview:title];
} 
[title setText:[[videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]];
```

Previous answer author is right. It could be better to use your own subclass of UITableViewCell.
I don't see any memory release. Are you using automatic reference counting?